# Angular 2 App broken after moving component into sub folder

Tags: angular

I moved a simple "about" component which serves up an "about us" page, into a sub folder. Re-ran `tsc` and my app will no longer run. When I revert back, its fine. Can someone explain what is happening and how to fix it? I am trying to put all of my components into sub-folders.

THIS IS THE ERROR:

(index):43 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:3003/app/components/about/about.component.ts.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3003/app/main.js

Comment: did you update all of your reference paths to the "about us" component?

Comment: Yes like ./ to ../

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. WebStorm is trying to fix the new paths and added .ts to the import statement. Now it is working.